# Не выдаёт значения после выполнения комманды. discord.py+sqlite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, discord, discord.py

При выполнение комманды в @bot.commands не работает cursor.execute. Ничего не выдаёт при print

```
@bot.command() 
async def ans(ctx, useranswer):
    if useranswer == answer:
        status = 0
        await ctx.send("Correct! +100points")
        author_id = str(message.author.id)
        cursor.execute(f"select points from profiles where userid = {author_id}")
        amount = cursor.fetchall()
        print(amount) #ничего не выдаёт скорее всего не работает cursor.execute с @bot.commands. C if message.content == он работает и выдаёт значения.
        if amount == author_id:
            pass
        with open('amount2.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(amount))
        with open('amount2.txt') as f:
            amount2txt = f.read()
        amount2 = amount2txt.strip("[(',)]")
        amount3 = amount2 + 15
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE profiles SET points = {amount3} where userid = {author_id}")
        db.commit()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Incorrect! -100points!")
```

Comment: Напишите `user id` слитно в коде и в db

Comment: В db userid уже слитно, в коде исправил, но результата нету. Всё так же в консоли ничего не высветилось и в .txt файле ничего не записалось..

Comment: В db есть юзер с таким айди? В колонке `points` есть значение?

Comment: Да всё есть. При комманде &profile aka if message.content == "&profile" база данных работает и все значения высвечивает. Как пытаюсь с @bot.commands получить данные базы ничего не высвечивает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

message -> ctx

```
@bot.command() 
async def ans(ctx, useranswer):
    if useranswer == answer:
        status = 0
        await ctx.send("Correct! +100points")
        author_id = str(ctx.author.id)
        cursor.execute(f"select points from profiles where userid = {author_id}")
        amount = cursor.fetchall()
        print(amount) #ничего не выдаёт скорее всего не работает cursor.execute с @bot.commands. C if message.content == он работает и выдаёт значения.
        if amount == author_id:
            pass
        with open('amount2.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(amount))
        with open('amount2.txt') as f:
            amount2txt = f.read()
        amount2 = amount2txt.strip("[(',)]")
        amount3 = amount2 + 15
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE profiles SET points = {amount3} where userid = {author_id}")
        db.commit()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Incorrect! -100points!")
```